# Google Sheets - Increment cell value with ARRAYFORMULA and based on value from another field

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, cumulative-sum

I have a spreadsheet I'm creating and I have an ARRAYFORMULA for incrementing the number of a field based on another field. My formula looks like this (NOTE: my rows start on row 4 that is why there is a ROW(A4:A)-3):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A4:A) = 4, 1, IF(B4:B = 1, ROW(A4:A)-3, (ROW(A4:A)-3)-(B4:B - 1))))
```

What I'm doing is creating groups (A) and then have a sequence counter (B) which is the number of rows within the group. I want the result to look like this where the A just picks up from where it left off (Note: B is manually entered):

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |

However, my result is looking this this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 |

I know ROW gets me the row number but when I try and use INDEX formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(G4:G) = 4, 1, IF(H4:H = 1, INDEX(G4:G, ROW(G4:G)-1, 1) + 1, INDEX(G4:G, ROW(G4:G)-1, 1)))
```

to get the actual value of the prior cell I get a constant flashing like it's stuck in an infinite loop of some sort. I know I can probably just accomplish this without ARRAYFORMULA however, this spreadsheet will be shared and contains many other formulas that I just don't want people to have to cut and copy from the row above and get formulas all messed up. I'm dealing with non-technical people that need something to just work very simple.

Sample:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FqndR4oTm_uaO7aUxYSgb3p0bZ6yBz-KnjUAD8kctd4/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: It would be simpler if you shared an editable sample with data starting on row 4

Comment: @MattKing That would be too easy. ;) I updated my question with a sample link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(A4:A, A4:A, ROW(A4:A), "<="&ROW(A4:A)))
```

[image]

---

reverse:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B4:B))<=
 SEQUENCE(1, COUNTA(B4:B)))*IF(INDIRECT("B4:B"&COUNTA(B4:B)+ROW(B4)-1)=1, 1)), 
 SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B4:B))^0))
```

[image]

Comment: sorry I think you might have some confusion with what the issue is. As I mentioned the B column is manually entered. I'm looking for the correct numbering of the A column.